# Select rows where a multiple values in one column map to the same value in another

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table with the user ID, address and postcode. There can be multiple entries for each user ID (it stores all their previous addresses and post codes) but there has been an issue where addresses have been updated but the postcodes have not. 
I need to find all user IDs where, for a given user, an address has changed but the postcode was not updated.

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID | Address | Postcode |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | Town A  | abcde2   |
|  1 | Town B  | abcde2   |
|  3 | Town B  | defgh6   |
|  3 | Town B  | defgh6   |
|  4 | Town C  | ijklm7   |
|  5 | Town A  | ijklm7   |
|  5 | Town C  | abcde2   |
+----+---------+----------+
```

The output should be:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID | Address | Postcode |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | Town A  | abcde2   |
|  1 | Town B  | abcde2   |
+----+---------+----------+
```

or simply just the IDs.

Comment: You want rows with the same `postcode` but different `address` for the same `id`? But why are rows with id 5 returned, they got different postcodes and different addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for records having the same `id` and `postcode` but with a different `address`.

You can achieve this with a simple `JOIN`, that defines above conditions in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.address,
    t1.postcode
FROM 
    table t1
    INNER JOIN table t2 
        ON  t2.id       = t1.id
        AND t2.postcode = t1.postcode
        AND t1.address  <> t2.address 
;
```

Please note that there seems to be an issue in your expected data : as per the specification you gave, no records should be displayed for id `5`...

Comment: Oh yes you are correct about number 5 thank you. I am getting an error however that table t2 does not exist, do I need to create one before executing this? If yes, is there any work arounds as it could take some time to get permissions to create tables in the environment I'm working in

Comment: @CMartin you did not actually provide the real name of the table where your data is stored, so I used generic name `table`. You need to replace that with the real name of the table that stores your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code would solve your issue:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.ADDRESS, A.POSTCODE FROM 
TABLE A
JOIN TABLE B ON A.ID=B.ID AND A.ADDRESS=B.ADDRESS AND A.POSTCODE<>B.POSTCODE;
```

Comment: I am getting an error however that table B does not exist, do I need to create one before executing this? If yes, is there any work arounds as it could take some time to get permissions to create tables in the environment I'm working in. It is also giving me an error when I use the word "table" in a statement

Comment: @CMartin no, you do not need to create any tables. Simply replace "TABLE" with your table name in the above query and you're good to go!